# Неизвестная ошибка при подключении к MySQLi и проблема с ООП

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

**PHP, OOP, MySQL**
У меня проблема с подключением к базе данных MySQL, после того как данные для mysqli_connect() поместил в объект, возвращаемый из статической функции из класса.
Ранее, когда хранил данные для `mysqli_connect()` в переменных, и после писал `$link = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);` всё работало. 
 Сейчас я написал класс, в нём статическую функцию возвращающую объект с данными:
Класс:

```
<?php
class aaa114net
{
    static function getMysqliLink(){
        $host = 'localhost';
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';
        $database = 'database';
        $data = (object)["host"=>$host,"username"=>$username,"password"=>$password,"database"=>$database];
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Скрипт вызова:

```
<?php
require('class/net.myclass.php');
$data = aaa114net::getMysqliLink();
$link = mysqli_connect($data->host,$data->username,$data->password,$data->database);
$query = "SELECT `столбец` FROM таблица WHERE `столбец`='".$variable."'";
$request = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($request);
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Возвращает: `Ошибка` и больше ничего.
Помогите пожалуйста, в чём моя ошибка ?

P.S. PHP v.7.2.1, данные для входа базу данных указаны верно, то что в переменной `$query` работало и сейчас работает на сайте (я на локальном хосте провожу тесты, использую MAMP Pro).

Comment: убедитесь, что `$link !== false` и проверьте ошибки подключения с помощью соответствующих функций. Также проверьте лог или включите отображение ошибок/нотисов, увидите там популярную на этом ресурсе строку как mysql_query ожидает ресурс а получает булевое значение.

Comment: вам самим то не кажется лютыми костылями, то как вы определяете настройки? создаете локальные переменные, записываете их в массив, делаете из него объект, и потом обращаетесь к его свойствам. зачем это все? `return [ 'host' => "localhost", ....]` потом и распаковать его можете в `mysql_connect(...$data);`. Редактирование массива настроек куда нагляднее и удобнее, чем задание значений переменных, не говоря уже о том, что в процессе вы кучу ошибок и опечаток сделать можете.

Comment: Локальные переменные это я просто пока ООП учу, перед обновлением кода всё расписываю.
Я проверил имеет ли $link значение false скриптом :
`if($link !== false){
    header('Location: notfalse');
}
elseif($link == false){
    header('Location: false');
}
else{header('Location: unknownbool');}`
И $link оказалась false... Что это может значить ? (Я попробую сейчас убрать объект и оставить массив)

Comment: дак вы сделайте `print_r($data)` и посмотрите, что за учетные данные у вас там указываются.

Comment: в случае отсутствия отладчика проверять значения надо через `var_dump` или `print_r`, а не ифами с хэдерами

Comment: Я получил mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in ... Данные указаны верно... Спасибо за помощь, я попробую дальше разобраться сам.

Comment: мне кажется тут уже и так все ясно)

Comment: @Manitikyl, да, я сразу залил на сам сайт, и всё стало хорошо, проблема какая-то с моим локальным MySQL сервером...

Comment: @teran, спасибо, я вместо объекта сделал переменную, всё подправил, и теперь всё работает

Comment: @teran, вот собственно говоря результат работы: [Скрипт подобия социальной сети на моём сайте](http://aaa114-project.tk/network) :)
P.S. [Сам сайт](http://aaa114-project.tk/network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

class aaa114net {

    private static $connection;

    public static function getDb() {
        if (!self::$connection) {
            $dbConfig = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/db.php');
            /*
            <?php
            return [
                'hostname' => 'localhost',
                'database' => 'test',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
            ];
            */

            self::$connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbConfig['hostname']};dbname={$dbConfig['database']}", $dbConfig['username'], $dbConfig['password']);
        }

        return self::$connection;
    }
}

$query = "  SELECT 
                * 
            FROM `users` 
            WHERE `user_id` = :bind";

$sth = aaa114net::getDb()->prepare($query);
$sth->bindParam(':bind', $variable);
$sth->execute();
print_r($sth->fetchAll());
```